# jQuery to Clone Table Rows - Only Half Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am a very basic novice when it comes to jQuery. I can find my way through usually by searching for snippets and ammending to suit my needs.

Here is one I cannot understand. I have a div, with 3 nested divs, then each nested div has a table, followed by a link.

```
<div id="exercise_container">
  <div class="weight_reps" style="border: 1px gray dashed">
    <h3 colspan="3"></h3>
    <table>
      <tr>{headers}</tr>
      <tr>{some data}</tr> 
      <tr>{some data}</tr>
    </table>
    <a class="addSet" href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="weight_reps" style="border: 1px gray dashed">
    <h3 colspan="3"></h3>
    <table>
      <tr>{headers}</tr>
      <tr>{some data}</tr> 
      <tr>{some data}</tr>
    </table>
    <a class="addSet" href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="weight_reps" style="border: 1px gray dashed">
    <h3 colspan="3"></h3>
    <table>
      <tr>{headers}</tr>
      <tr>{some data}</tr> 
      <tr>{some data}</tr>
    </table>
    <a class="addSet" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The links are to clone the second row of the table and ammend it to the bottom (plus some other stuff but the basic function here is odd).

This is the jQuery that executes when the links are clicked:

```
<script>
someCounter = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.addSet').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $table = $(this).prev("table");
    var $row = $table.find('tr:eq(2)');
    var $clonedRow = $row.clone(true);
    $clonedRow.hide();
    $table.append($clonedRow);
    $clonedRow.show('slow');    
    someCounter++;
  });
});
</script>
```

Now, this works for the **first two** divs, i.e. when clicked, an extra row gets added to the table in its section...but it does not work on the 3rd! I cannot understand why. I am doing this in Codeigniter so the divs are all produced in the same way identically.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "the divs are produced in the same way" -- Are all the divs present when the document is rendered?  Before you hook up the click event, do `console.log($('.addSet').length)` to make sure the event handler is registered on that element. You could also try event delegation: `$('body').on('click', '.addSet')` I believe is the syntax (without looking it up).

Answer (score 0):

I have coppied and pasted your html and javascript to the Jsfiddler and edited some parts to make it work

1. there seams to be a error in your html and when you paste the html in JSfiddler it highlights the first div's end tag what i did
   was replace the first div with second div (since you said the div's
   are identical)
2. also i have change the structure of the tables to add the data inside columns( tags) rather than placing the data directly
   inside a row since jquery doesn't seam to be able to select the
   table rows when you add  without
3. also i removed the  someCounter variable since it's not used anywhere

you can find the solution here  http://jsfiddle.net/ttscy06h/ `enter code here`

Comment: Your example works as I would like mine to...I just can't figure out why mine doesn't do it. If I copy and paste my original HTML into your JSFiddle, I get the same behaviour. Top two work, third one does not!

Comment: did you copy get an error when you paste the html in JSfiddller

Comment: try copying the html in my solution and pasting it in you code